# specific nodejs version, opsworks_ruby, aws, chef 12

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, ubuntu-16.04, aws-opsworks, cookbook

Can anyone point me in the write direction for installing a specific nodejs version when running chef 12 on AWS opsworks?

Infrastructure: `EC2`,`t2.micro`,`ubuntu 16.04 LTS`

custom cookbook:

File: `recipes/default.rb`

```
node.default['packages-cookbook'] = [
 'libmysqlclient-dev',
 'libmysqlclient20',
 'pkg-config',
 'libswitch-perl',
 'nodejs',
 'yarn'
]
```

File: `Berksfile`

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
cookbook 'opsworks_ruby', '1.8.0'
cookbook 'packages', '~> 1.0.0'
metadata
```

File: `metadata.rb`

```
chef_version '>= 12.1' if respond_to?(:chef_version)
depends 'opsworks_ruby', '1.8.0'
depends 'packages', '~> 1.0.0'
```

AWS `Custom json`

```
"ruby-ng": {
    "ruby_version": "2.4"
},
"nodejs": {
    "version": "8.9.1"
}
```

The build is failing due to installed nodejs version of `4.2.6` when the build requires a higher version. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sorry all, my bad forgot to add `include_recipe: 'nodejs'`

Comment: Is your nodejs recipe before your deployment recipe? It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via poise-javascript:

```
javascript_runtime '8.9.1'
```

or in a role/wrapper:

```
default['poise-javascript']['options']['version'] = '8.9.1'
```

By default it installs from the static binaries from the NodeJS project so it should support any version.